# Best practices: Organizing CSS files within a large Backbone.js app, and accounting for image sprites?

Tags: css, backbone.js, css-sprites, sprite-sheet

I inherited a Backbone.js app that has one stylesheet with 3000 lines.

I would like to refactor this into multiple stylesheets (and maybe start using a preprocessor like SASS).  I would also like to start using CSS sprites for my images, since I believe this could shave a full second or two off load times.

Is there a best practice for splitting a mega-CSS file Backbone.js app into multiple CSS files?

What about for organizing my rules and sprites so that when I add a new image, and the sprite generator "optimizes" the space-layout of the sprite, I don't have to hunt down every single selector and change the background-position coordinates?

I was thinking of keeping a separate "sprites.css" file (it would get minified and concatenated for production deploy) that simply contained all of the positions and height/width values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**For the question about organize the splitting into multiple sass files when developing :**

- Try http://patternlab.io/, a demo can be found here : http://demo.patternlab.io/, as inspiration.
- Another suggestion is [outline](https://github.com/htmlzengarden/outline/) which is a skeleton of front end. ( what i use )
- Take a look at [OOCSS concept](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-css-what-how-and-why--net-6986)

This is just files organization, but that might save you some lines of css. 
More than that, that will help in maintainability and Don't Repeat Yourself.

**As a suggestion for optimizing :**

I compile my sass files into page specific css : homepage.css will need core.sass which import the basic need of each page + homepage.sass which import files for the content. You can of course split it as you own needs.

Another thing you can do is load the core.css (from core.sass) in the <head>. Then async load the homepage.css (from homepage.sass) once the dom content is loaded. If you use Backbone with Require.js, be careful because require.js does not do async css files ( yepnope.js does it, but the order of loading is synchronous). There might be an javascript synchronous loader library which fit your needs, somewhere.

You can even let the html be loaded, then async load your(s) css file(s). But as the content of your app will be filled with Backbone Collection or whatever, i am not sure this last option will fit your needs.

The important thing is to load only the needed css for each page.

Another suggesition, lint your css with [csslint](http://csslint.net/), will help a lot

**For sprites**, the only thought i have so far is [SassyJson](http://hugogiraudel.com/2014/01/20/json-in-sass/) (for Sass) which is relatively new.

This is what i do, i am sure you can go deeper in optimization, but i guess that's a good begining.

Answer (score 0):

Either Sass or [less](http://lesscss.org/) would be a great way to fix the single-huge-CSS file problem. (This isn't really related to Backbone, though. It could apply to any HTML-based project.)

To start, you can immediately break up the single file into several smaller files that you then import in the main file. On most of my projects, I use a build tool like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to  compile the Sass or less source into a single .css file to include in the HTML file, so only one HTTP request is needed for the CSS.

The CSS extension languages like Sass/less also let you use variables to solve the CSS sprite problem: create a file with variables for the sprite positions, then use only the variables in your Sass rules. When the sprite positions change, just update the variables and recompile.

Finally, using Sass/less will let you start small at first and gradually refactor more as you need to. That has the advantage of producing useful benefits immediately with little effort -- say, just splitting up the big CSS file into several smaller ones -- and then adding more advanced features over time, like refactoring to use variables, macros, and nested CSS rules.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't really give me anything new.  This doesn't answer my question about sprite-friendly CSS (since adding a new image can change the locations of every image).  It also doesn't offer hints about efficiently extracting CSS into separate files (which rules belong in which file).